# User Input Interface Name

Tags: php, user-interface

What do you call this type of user interface? The one in the right side of the picture? The "bar" should be draggable from 0 to 5 depending on what is the appropriate.. and how can I create that for PHP? Thanks!

[image: the right input interface]

Comment: it can be done with javascript not php http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: @mgraph ah okay.. what is it called and do you have any reference how I can use this? thanks!

Comment: okay just saw your link thanks for that.. you may want to include it in answers so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just read jquery UI Doc it easy to use http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#multiple-vertical

Answer (score 1):

A [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).

Comment: thanks! sorry, that may sound like a very newbie question.. thanks for the link too